# I love you, and will always do? Or always will?

Tags: word-choice, word-order, do, will-future

My girlfriend (who's first language is not English) said to me the other day 'I love you, and I will always do'. I then proceeded to make the argument that that didn't make sense, and that it would have to be 'And I always will'.

Could someone please clarify which would be the most desirable/correct?

Comment: Both work perfectly. There's neither a grammatical nor a semantic issue there. (What's grammar between lovers, anyway?)

Comment: I have a slight reservation about Kris’ comment. English is a funny old language.  As Kris hints, a romantic conversation is not a linguistic context (‘register’) matters, so long as it is understood.  Even in a romantic novel, that would be so.  However, for more formal, less relaxed contexts, ending with the word ‘do’ does not sound quite right.  I would expect “... and I always will.”, or “and I will always do so.”.   The exceptions are:  the famous “I do” at the altar, and the casual “Will do” in response to an order or request.  But this is a very minor matter.

Comment: arguing with 'i love you' if full of pitfalls!

Comment: She must really love you if you drop some argument about grammar during a heartfelt moment.

Answer (score 0):

I love you and always will. 
You would not use”do” i this sentence

Answer (score 0):

The most desirable here will vary from person to person, and correctness on which language rules they subscribe to. I can say that "I always will" sounds more fluid to me, but the added "do" provides an affirmation which is important to take into account when considering desirability. After all, would you prefer someone to say "I love you", or "I do love you"? Particularly when considering the circumstances in which each are often said, I suggest most might say "I do".

But addressing the point of correctness in a loose sense, to say 'I will always do' is similar to the Irish version "I always will do". In the first case the emphasis is placed on the length of the action, suggesting commitment - in the second case the emphasis is placed on the affirmative, and is used as a common wordtype-pair - I cannot say either are incorrect. Ultimately what is important here is the added affirmation behind the word "do", and while it is implied that one does love when they say that they love, the emphasis on the enduring nature of her love, via word order, is endearing.

> **Finally**,
>
> In an effort to compromise you might agree on something like "I do love you and I always will".